# Avoid parentheses around optional header material in theorem environment

Tags: beamer, theorems

I would like to get rid of the around the optinal header material in my theorem environment. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{MyHypo}{Hypothesis}
\begin{frame}
\begin{MyHypo}[insert text]
This is my hypothesis
\end{MyHypo} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there another option for the setbeamertemplate to keep the numbering but avoid the ( ) for the text?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: sry just forgot to paste the \documentcalss{beamer}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine the `theorem begin`/`numbered` template:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@theorem begin@numbered\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{numbered}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi% (\inserttheoremaddition)
    }%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{MyHypo}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{MyHypo}[insert text]
  This is my hypothesis
\end{MyHypo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With the redefinition, *all* theorems under the `numbered` template will have the parentheses removed.

Comment: Nice! So `beamer` does not make use of `amsthm`!

Comment: @Sigur: It does, but it redefines certain things.

Comment: Nice! I tried to do the same for the ams style beamer template, changing numbered to ams style, but ran into errors. Any idea how I should proceed? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou: Perhaps consider a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)?

Comment: sure, here is the new post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371280/avoid-parentheses-around-optional-header-material-in-theorem-environment-for-ams thanks!