# Avoid parentheses around optional header material in theorem environment for ams style?

Tags: beamer, amsthm

This is a follow-up question on [Avoid parentheses around optional header material in theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/avoid-parentheses-around-optional-header-material-in-theorem-environment).

I want to do exactly the same (remove the parenthesis around the theorem optional header in a theorem, in beamer), but for ams style theorems. I am indeed using ams style theorems, not the numbered ones, i.e. I use `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]`, not `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]` as in the [other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/avoid-parentheses-around-optional-header-material-in-theorem-environment). How should I adjust the code there?

A naive change of `\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{numbered}` to `\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{ams style}` ran into the error: *LaTeX Error: Command \beamer@@tmpop@theorem begin@ams style already defined.*

Here is the code that works for [numbered], and that I would like to adapt for [ams style]:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@theorem begin@numbered\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{numbered}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi% (\inserttheoremaddition)
    }%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{MyHypo}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{MyHypo}[insert text]
  This is my hypothesis
\end{MyHypo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with `amsmath`.  theorems are defined by `amsthm`, so i've changed the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{ams style}` is defined in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`,  ll. 771. To remove the parenthesis:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\newtheorem{MyHypo}{Hypothesis}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremheadfont
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
      \inserttheorempunctuation
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{MyHypo}[insert text]
  This is my hypothesis
\end{MyHypo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]