# Avoid parentheses when optional header material is not visible? (theorem environment for ams style)

Tags: beamer, overlays, amsthm

I am looking for an extension to the solved question in [Avoid parentheses around optional header material in theorem environment for ams style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371280/241569).

I would like to have optional header text for a theorem environment on some but not on all slides. Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{thm*}[\only<beamer:2->{additional information}]
        My Theorem  
    \end{thm*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, slide 2 looks as expected, but slide 1 prints `Theorem ().` Is there a way to adapt the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371284/241569) to take the overlay into account?

**EDIT**

I have also tried

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{thm*}\only<beamer:2->{[additional information]}
        My Theorem  
    \end{thm*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which is worse; LaTeX does not see `additional information` as optional header text, but as content of the environment itself.

**EDIT 2**

Like [suggested below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596066/241569), I had considered deleting the parentheses from the command, then hard-coding them in each instance of an optional header of an environment. I would like to avoid doing that, since I may have many instances of such optional headers.

Comment: Why not just apply the `[additional information]` on only the slides where it's wanted?  Or are the parentheses not wanted there?  (That's not entirely clear.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am not sure what is unclear or what you are suggesting. In the MWE that I gave (first piece of code), I have the following problem: When the frame is shown for the first time (Slide 1), the theorem environment is printed as `Theorem ().`, where I would instead like it to print `Theorem.`. The second time the frame is shown (Slide 2), it shows as `Theorem (additional information).`, as expected and desired. How should I "just apply it where it's wanted"?

Comment: It's not clear to me why it's necessary to insert a test into the definition.  Why can't the ordinary `\begin{thm*}` be used when no addition is wanted, and `\begin{thm*}[...]` when it is?  (Wanting to omit parentheses is a separate matter that I'm not addressing.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I still don't understand what I am being unclear about, but let me try again: I want the text in `[...]` to only appear on some pages of the final pdf, not all of them, despite having only one single `thm*` environment in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You ask whether it is possible to adapt solutions to the question

[Avoid parentheses around optional header material in theorem environment for ams style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371280)

so that the result of adapting forms a solution to your issue.*

*The issue described in that question differs from the issue described in your question:*

*That question asks for additional information, if present, not to be surrounded by parentheses.*

*Your question is about not providing additional information at all with some slides.*

*I think with your question adapting the solution for a different issue is probably not the best approach and might result in something unnecessarily complicated.*

---

Just use `\alt` for forking whether an optional argument is to be supplied to `\begin{thm*}` at all:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem\vphantom{()}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<beamer:1-10>
  % Assume you don't wish additional info on frames 1,3 and 6:
  \alt<beamer:1,3,6>%
  {\begin{thm*}}%
  {%
    \begin{thm*}[{additional information on slide
                  \only<beamer:2>{2}%
                  \only<beamer:4>{4}%
                  \only<beamer:5>{5}%
                  \only<beamer:7->{7ff}%
                }]%
  }%
  My Theorem
  \end{thm*}
  \par
  \vfill
  \begingroup
  \noindent\tiny
  (Frame \insertframenumber, slide \insertslidenumber/%
  \number\numexpr\insertframeendpage-\insertframestartpage+1\relax.\\
  The heading of the theorem shall not have additional
  information on slides 1, 3 and 6.)\par
  \endgroup
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are right; adapting may not be the best approach, and I should have worded my intro better - I just attempted to show that I had looked up possible solutions myself before posting here. Your solution looks great; I never would have considered putting `\begin{thm*}` into `\alt` by itself. Knowing that that can be done opens up MANY possibilities!

Comment: @Anna I have full empathy for your statement: When I started using TeX/LaTeX about 25 years ago, it took me a great while to get used to TeX's expansion-related programming paradigm. ;-) The ways of approaching things in TeX/LaTeX often are counter‑intuitive for people who are not used to TeX's concept of also being a macro‑language, which in the stage of expansion basically is about shifting tokens around, but are used to object‑oriented/procedural/functional programming languages where things get carried out _after_ compilation, by running the compiled program, and where the concept of  ...

Comment: @Anna ... , and where the concept of "token and expansion" merely plays a subordinate rôle for the programmer when it is about compiler-directives. ;-)

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Anna You're welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: remove the parenthesis with the solution from the other question, then add them manually in the theorem (together with a space).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremheadfont%
      \inserttheoremname%
      \inserttheoremnumber%
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\inserttheoremaddition\fi%
      \inserttheorempunctuation%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{thm*}[\only<beamer:2->{ (additional information)}]
        My Theorem  
    \end{thm*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: you can also apply the parentheses automatically using some string manipulation with the `xstring` package. However, this is probably less robust, so I would advise to use the manual solution above. But in case you want to try here a version using the following steps:

0. Check if the optional argument contains `\only`. If yes:
1. Count the number of syntax units in `\inserttheoremaddition`. The text of the optional argument is the last syntax unit (here: `{additional information}`)
2. Store that syntax unit in a temporary macro
3. Make `xstring` look inside syntax units
4. Count the number of characters in the text of the argument
5. Extract this number of characters from the text. This effectively strips the surrounding `{}`.
6. Stop looking inside the syntax units
7. Substitute the text unit for the stripped unit with a space and parentheses added

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xstring}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremheadfont%
      \inserttheoremname%
      \inserttheoremnumber%
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else%
      \IfBeginWith{\inserttheoremaddition}{\only}{%
      \StrLen{\inserttheoremaddition}[\grouplen]%
      \StrChar{\inserttheoremaddition}{\grouplen}[\myarg]%
      \exploregroups%
      \StrLen{\myarg}[\arglen]%
      \StrLeft{\myarg}{\arglen}[\newarg]%
      \noexploregroups%
      \StrSubstitute{\inserttheoremaddition}{\myarg}{{ (\newarg)}}%
      }%
      { (\inserttheoremaddition)}\fi%
      \inserttheorempunctuation%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{thm*}[\only<beamer:2->{additional information}]
        My Theorem  
    \end{thm*}
    \begin{thm*}[Header]
        My Theorem  
    \end{thm*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did try that myself, but I have too many of those environments in my document, so I would rather not hard code the parentheses. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Anna I added an edit that applies the parentheses automatically. Probably the manual version is more robust though, so maybe it is better to use a few minutes to add the parentheses yourself.

Comment: @Marijn -- What's the difference here compared with just entering in the source `\begin{thm*} <theorem text>` when no optional information is wanted, and `\begin{thm*}[additional information] <theorem text>` when the optional information *is* wanted?  Is this something special with `beamer`?  I see to be missing something here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Now I see what I was unclear about. Yes, beamer is special: "In beamer, a presentation consists of a series of frames. Each frame in turn may consist of several slides (if there is more than one, they are called overlays)" ([beameruserguide](https://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), p. 22). The single frame of my MWE consisted of 2 slides; only one of which was supposed to contain `[additional information]`. The other I want to behave like it would if there was no optional header text, but instead `Theorem ().` is printed.

Comment: @Marijn Unfortunately, the second solution is indeed not robust: When I now type `\begin{thm*}[Header]` (so this `thm*` environment is with optional header that is not in overlay), then the output is `TheoremHeade (r).`

Comment: @Anna -- Thanks.  Got it now.  (I've used beamer, but never had to include theorems.  On the other hand, have had about 25 years of experience with theorems/`amsthm` in journals.  Quite a different environment.)

Comment: @Anna I added an edit that checks if you are using `\only`, and if not then don't do the string processing. But this of course may fail in other occasions, so check the ouput carefully if you want to use this - or add the parentheses manually and live care-free :)

Comment: @Marjin Thanks, but there are still some issues. Smaller issue: I could now never use, say, `\begin{thm*}[Abc\only<handout>{ def}]`, as that would result in `TheoremAbc`. Larger issue: A frame with `\only<1>{\begin{thm*} My Theorem \end{thm*}}` results in the error `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{frame}`. If I replace `1` by `-2`, I get two such errors.

Comment: @Anna the larger issue is solved, when I added the check for `\only` I misplaced a `\fi`. The code in the current edit works also with `\only<1>{\begin{thm*}`. The smaller issue is actually more difficult, it is easy to add a space automatically before the `abc` but the correct placement of parentheses in all overlays becomes rather complex in that case.

Comment: @Anna I found an easy way to solve also the small issue: check if the optional argument begins with `\only`, if yes put the parentheses inside the `\only` group, if not put them around the whole argument.

Comment: @Marijn The error is gone. Compilation time is now insane, but that is probably due to the counting nature of the solution. There is *still* an issue: If I write `\begin{thm*}[\only<beamer>{first}\only<handout>{second}]`, then it prints perfectly in the handout version (namely `Theorem (second)`), but not in the beamer version (namely `Theoremfirst`).

Comment: @Anna with _two_ onlys the replacement should be done in two places whereas the code only (pun intended...) does one replacement. I think the code would get rather messy if this feature would also be added. Maybe here you could settle for `\only<beamer>{ (first)}\only<handout>{second}`? Free parentheses for the 2nd \only :)

Comment: @Marijn Ha, that's fair. Thanks for the suggestion!