# Beamer flush right in title

Tags: beamer, numbering, citing, titles, block

I am currently working on some presentation with latex-beamer.

Now i've got some theorems where I want to add some context to where it comes from (aka. citations).
And I want them to appear where you would typically put the description/name of the theorem.

Naturally I tried flushright which obviously wasn't so smart, and two details need to be fixed.

1.) I really don't want double braces when citing, as the description would generate (name) and with a citation it would be ([name]). I left this from the MWE since adding a bib would seem to much.

2.) I want the citation appear on the right side of the theorems header.

thanks in advance

(I added two pictures, one of the compiled MWE and the second one on how it should look like, just without the blue bar)

Here I provide a MWE with some context on how it should not look.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer} 
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] 

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] %Numbered Theorems
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A wonderful frame}
\begin{thm}[replace with citation]
Let $\varepsilon<0$. 
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[\flushright Foo]
Let $\varepsilon>0$. 
\end{thm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is my broken MWE:
[image: My broken MWE]

And here is some version of my goal but with missing numbering:
[image: My goal]

Answer (score 1):

So, taking some time I realized that there already exists some part of the answer.

Looking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/avoid-parentheses-around-optional-header-material-in-theorem-environment) you find this code from Werner. Modifying this with some `\hfill` and a few braces helps out for this presentation.

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@theorem begin@numbered\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{numbered}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi% (\inserttheoremaddition)
    }%
}
\makeatother
```